# Flutter, how to dispose textController

Tags: flutter, dart, dispose, setstate

I'm learning Flutter and I have in my app, two textFields linked to textControllers in an AlertDialog to get the input from a user as text and display it in cards in the body of the screen. My problem, that I can't solve on my own, is that after I added setState(() {}) in the 'Save' button of the AlertDialog, for the text to acutally get displayed on the screen in body, well after this change the text entered in the TextFields doesn't get cleared aymore after pressing 'Save'.

My Code:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
  DummyDataProvider notes;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    titleController.dispose();
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

The textControllers in question:

```
MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      final title = titleController.text;
                      final text = textController.text;
                      NoteProvider.insertNote({'title': title, 'text': text});
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
```

What i mean by text not disposing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zztqd.jpg,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBGX1.jpg

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify the description of your issue and narrow down the code you've shared. 150 lines of code for an issue with a `TextController` not clearing is excessive. Also, you shared code that we can't use as we don't have the classes and it's not relevant to the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I've seem to have needed it as I'm new on this platform. I went on and edited my post, I hope is more clear and on point now. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `clear()`?

```dart
final _textController = TextEditingController();
.....
.....
onPressed: () {
    _textController.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your text controllers.

For example in onpressed:

`titleController = new TextEditingController();`

`textController = new TextEditingController();`

Set state is not required for this.

Comment: So I tried your solution but now I have this error that I don't have the knowledge to solve, maybe you can help me make it work:https://imgur.com/a/azvbxHr. Also thank you for your prompt answer

Comment: Edited my answer check now. Should've only initialised the controller not it's text.

Comment: avoid doin this @ADNANJAKATI

Answer (score 0):

```
TextEditingController
```

Is very expensive object, don't create it often

just use

`TextEditingController.text == '';`

to clear the text,

Comment: ignore the extra =